# Convergence in probability implies convergence in mean square for normal mean $0$ random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X_1, X_2, ...$ be i.i.d. normal random variables with mean $0$. I want to show that if $X_n \rightarrow 0$ in probability, then $X_n \rightarrow 0$ in mean square.

I am a little confused with this question. If $X_n \rightarrow 0$ in probability then $X_n \rightarrow 0$ in distribution. I can't continue with this question without knowing anything about the variance. How do I apporach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Ee^{itX_n}=e^{itm_n}e^{-t^{2}\sigma_n^{2}/2}$ where $m_n$ is the mean and $\sigma_n^{2}$ is the variance of $X_n$. Convergence in probability (or even convergence in distribution) implies convergence of characteristic functions. Hence, $e^{itm_n}e^{-t^{2}\sigma_n^{2}/2} \to 1$ for all $t$. Taking absolute value we see that  $e^{-\sigma_n^{2}/2} \to 1 $, so $\sigma_n^{2} \to 0$.